# Can experience as a high school teacher or freelance tutor be useful for graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

If someone works as teacher in high school after completing his undergrad studies or works as a freelance tutor, can he write about it in his statement of purpose? Would such experience be considered as "Teaching experience"?

Comment: Both types of experience should be in the CV as well so I wouldn't waste the space in the statement just to repeat them. Rather, provide some more qualitative meaning/impact of these jobs on your overall purpose. Do they reflect good command of the subject? Make you aspire to be a teacher? Remind you of your passion of seeing the "Aha~!" faces, etc.? Try to make relevance to the program you are applying for.

Comment: For what it's worth I mentioned tutoring in my application and I've gotten acceptances to good schools so it definitely doesn't hurt *too* badly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the field that you are in, teaching is a valuable skill. In my experience as a graduate student it has only ever added value and is often included as a separate category on various applications. I would consider high school teaching and tutoring to both be great experiences that are worth including in an academic admissions context, especially if the subjects fell within your field of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Showing that you can teach is such a key skill, not only because it shows you can teach but it also shows you can present.
It also may make you more competitive to get funding through TAships!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110584)